# How to update status using subquery for below code in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_ATTENDANCE_DASHBOARD
AS
  PROCEDURE Proc_Dashboard(
      V_CommandType         VARCHAR2,
      V_LoginId             VARCHAR2,
      V_SignType            VARCHAR2,
      V_AttendanceDate      DATE,
      V_Year                VARCHAR2,
      V_Month               VARCHAR2,
      V_IPAddress           VARCHAR2,
      V_LogonUserName       VARCHAR2,
      V_WorkLocation        VARCHAR2,
      V_WorkLocationType    VARCHAR2,
      V_Company             VARCHAR2,
      V_UserType            VARCHAR2,
      V_ShiftName           VARCHAR2,
      V_Self_Covid_Status   VARCHAR2,
      V_Self_Covid_Remark   VARCHAR2,
      V_Family_Covid_Status VARCHAR2,
      V_Family_Covid_Remark VARCHAR2,
      V_UpdatedBy           VARCHAR2
      /*  curGetCalendar OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      curGetCovidStatus OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      curListCompanyName OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      curListTowerName OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      curAttendanceListByDate OUT SYS_REFCURSOR*/
    )
  AS
    V_Date DATE := TO_DATE (V_Year || '-' || V_Month || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  BEGIN
    IF V_CommandType = 'getCalendar' THEN
    WITH DaysInMonth (dates) AS
      (SELECT V_Date AS dates FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT INTERVAL '1' DAY (5) + dates
      FROM DaysInMonth
      WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM dates) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM V_Date)
      )
    SELECT dates FROM DaysInMonth;
    INSERT
    INTO T_ATTENDANCE_ATTENDANCE
      (
        LoginId,
        AttendanceDate,
        ShiftName,
        ShiftStartTime,
        ShiftEndTime,
        Active,
        AttendanceStatus
      )
    SELECT u.LoginID,
      d.dates,
      '' ,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      1,
      'Approved'
    FROM DaysInMonth d
    CROSS JOIN T_ATTENDANCE_USER_MASTER u
    WHERE extract(MONTH FROM dates) = extract(MONTH FROM V_Date)
    AND LoginId                     = V_LoginId
    AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT LoginId
      FROM T_ATTENDANCE_ATTENDANCE
      WHERE LoginId                          = V_LoginId
      AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATTENDANCEDATE ) = extract(YEAR FROM V_Date)
      AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM AttendanceDate) = extract(MONTH FROM V_Date)
      AND ACTIVE                             = 1
      );
    V_Date := INTERVAL '1' MONTH + V_Date;
  WITH DaysInMonth (dates) AS
    (SELECT V_Date AS dates FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT INTERVAL '1' DAY(5) + dates
    FROM DaysInMonth
    WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dates) = extract(MONTH FROM V_Date)
    )
  SELECT dates FROM DaysInMonth;
   INSERT INTO T_ATTENDANCE_ATTENDANCE
    (
      LoginId,
      AttendanceDate,
      ShiftName,
      ShiftStartTime,
      ShiftEndTime,
      Active,
      AttendanceStatus
    )
  SELECT u.LoginID,
    d.dates,
    '',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    1,
    'Approved'
  FROM DaysInMonth d
  CROSS JOIN T_ATTENDANCE_USER_MASTER u
  WHERE extract(MONTH FROM dates) = extract(MONTH FROM V_Date)
  AND LoginId                     = V_LoginId
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT LoginId
    FROM T_ATTENDANCE_ATTENDANCE
    WHERE LoginId                          = V_LoginId
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATTENDANCEDATE ) = extract(YEAR FROM V_date)
    AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM AttendanceDate) = extract(MONTH FROM V_date)
    AND ACTIVE                             = 1
    );
  OPEN curGetCalendar FOR SELECT AttendanceDate,
  ShiftName,
  TO_CHAR(AttendanceDate,'ddd') DAY,
  V_Year,
  V_Month ,
  TO_CHAR(SignIn, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt') SignIn,
  TO_CHAR(SignOut, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt') SignOut FROM T_ATTENDANCE_ATTENDANCE WHERE LoginId = V_LoginId AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATTENDANCEDATE) = V_Year AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM AttendanceDate) = V_Month AND ACTIVE = 1 order by AttendanceDate ASC;

--I am getting error here in below code
  
  Update   A
  set  A.ShiftName = case when to_char(TO_DATE(a.Attendancedate) ,'DAY')  in  ('SATURDAY') and week in (2,4) then 'WEEKLYOFF'
  when to_Char(TO_DATE(a.Attendancedate),'WW') in  ('SUNDAY') then 'WEEKLYOFF'
  else 'GENERAL1' end
  From
  (
  select attendancedate,shiftname, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by to_char(TO_DATE(attendancedate,'DAY') order by attendancedate) as  week  from T_ATTENDANCE_ATTENDANCE A1
  left join T_ATTENDANCE_USER_MASTER U on U.LoginId = A1.LoginId
  left join T_ATTENDANCE_EMPLOYEE_MASTER E on E.EmpID = U.EmpID
  where A1.loginid = V_LoginId and E.Company = '' and extract(year from attendancedate) = extract(year from Sysdate) and extract(month from attendancedate) = extract(month from
  Sysdate()) and nvl(shiftname,'') = ''
  ) A

END IF
END Proc_Dashboard;
END PKG_ATTENDANCE_DASHBOARD;
```

Comment: I could be wrong, I don't know Oracle, but normally a semi-colon (`;`) is a statement terminator... and you have it right in the middle of your statement.

Comment: when I remove semicolon then I am getting error on Update A  statment

Comment: And why did you remove the code formatting I added for you?  Its very hard to read a query in plain text, which is why the code formatting option is available.

Comment: After removing semicolon  i am getting error on UPDATE A   statement

Comment: And you need to post the actual error verbatim if you want assistance.

Comment: Displaying Syntax error PLSQL

Comment: I recommend consulting the official documentation - its very good and will almost certainly provide your answer. And if you want anyone to assist you, I suggest restoring the code formatting to your query so that its reabable.

Comment: I Have Posted complete code kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you (initially) posted is only partially Oracle. When fixed:

```
update a set
  a.shiftname = 
  (select case when to_char(to_date(a.attendancedate) ,'DAY') in ('SATURDAY') and a.week in (2,4) then 'WEEKLYOFF'
               when to_char(to_date(a.attendancedate),'WW')   in ('SUNDAY') then 'WEEKLYOFF'
               else 'GENERAL1' 
          end
   from (select attendancedate,
                shiftname, 
                row_number() over (partition by to_char(to_date(attendancedate,'DAY')) order by attendancedate) as week 
         from t_attendance_attendance a1
           left join t_attendance_user_master u     on u.loginid = a1.loginid
           left join t_attendance_employee_master e on e.empid   = u.empid 
         where a1.loginid = v_loginid 
           and e.company is null
           and extract (year from attendancedate)  = extract (year from sysdate) 
           and extract (month from attendancedate) = extract (month from sysdate) 
           and nvl(shiftname,'x') = 'x'
        ) a
  );
```

I don't know whether it will work or not (I don't have your tables nor data), but - at least - it should *compile*.

---

Similarly, for the whole procedure: you should terminate statements with a semi-colon; use a *proper* subquery in that `update`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_attendance_dashboard
AS
   PROCEDURE proc_dashboard (v_commandtype          VARCHAR2,
                             v_loginid              VARCHAR2,
                             v_signtype             VARCHAR2,
                             v_attendancedate       DATE,
                             v_year                 VARCHAR2,
                             v_month                VARCHAR2,
                             v_ipaddress            VARCHAR2,
                             v_logonusername        VARCHAR2,
                             v_worklocation         VARCHAR2,
                             v_worklocationtype     VARCHAR2,
                             v_company              VARCHAR2,
                             v_usertype             VARCHAR2,
                             v_shiftname            VARCHAR2,
                             v_self_covid_status    VARCHAR2,
                             v_self_covid_remark    VARCHAR2,
                             v_family_covid_status  VARCHAR2,
                             v_family_covid_remark  VARCHAR2,
                             v_updatedby            VARCHAR2/*  curGetCalendar OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                            curGetCovidStatus OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                            curListCompanyName OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                            curListTowerName OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                            curAttendanceListByDate OUT SYS_REFCURSOR*/
                                                            )
   AS
      v_date  DATE := TO_DATE (v_year || '-' || v_month || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
   BEGIN
      IF v_commandtype = 'getCalendar'
      THEN
         WITH
            daysinmonth (dates)
            AS
               (SELECT v_date AS dates FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT INTERVAL '1' DAY (5) + dates
                  FROM daysinmonth
                 WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM dates) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM v_date))
         SELECT dates
           FROM daysinmonth;

         INSERT INTO t_attendance_attendance (loginid,
                                              attendancedate,
                                              shiftname,
                                              shiftstarttime,
                                              shiftendtime,
                                              active,
                                              attendancestatus)
            SELECT u.loginid,
                   d.dates,
                   '',
                   NULL,
                   NULL,
                   1,
                   'Approved'
              FROM daysinmonth d CROSS JOIN t_attendance_user_master u
             WHERE     EXTRACT (MONTH FROM dates) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM v_date)
                   AND loginid = v_loginid
                   AND NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT loginid
                             FROM t_attendance_attendance
                            WHERE     loginid = v_loginid
                                  AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM attendancedate) =
                                      EXTRACT (YEAR FROM v_date)
                                  AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM attendancedate) =
                                      EXTRACT (MONTH FROM v_date)
                                  AND active = 1);

         v_date := INTERVAL '1' MONTH + v_date;

         WITH
            daysinmonth (dates)
            AS
               (SELECT v_date AS dates FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT INTERVAL '1' DAY (5) + dates
                  FROM daysinmonth
                 WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM dates) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM v_date))
         SELECT dates
           FROM daysinmonth;

         INSERT INTO t_attendance_attendance (loginid,
                                              attendancedate,
                                              shiftname,
                                              shiftstarttime,
                                              shiftendtime,
                                              active,
                                              attendancestatus)
            SELECT u.loginid,
                   d.dates,
                   '',
                   NULL,
                   NULL,
                   1,
                   'Approved'
              FROM daysinmonth d CROSS JOIN t_attendance_user_master u
             WHERE     EXTRACT (MONTH FROM dates) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM v_date)
                   AND loginid = v_loginid
                   AND NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT loginid
                             FROM t_attendance_attendance
                            WHERE     loginid = v_loginid
                                  AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM attendancedate) =
                                      EXTRACT (YEAR FROM v_date)
                                  AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM attendancedate) =
                                      EXTRACT (MONTH FROM v_date)
                                  AND active = 1);

         OPEN curgetcalendar FOR
              SELECT attendancedate,
                     shiftname,
                     TO_CHAR (attendancedate, 'ddd') cday,
                     v_year,
                     v_month,
                     TO_CHAR (signin, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt') signin,
                     TO_CHAR (signout, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt') signout
                FROM t_attendance_attendance
               WHERE     loginid = v_loginid
                     AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM attendancedate) = v_year
                     AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM attendancedate) = v_month
                     AND active = 1
            ORDER BY attendancedate ASC;

         --I am getting error here in below code

         UPDATE a
            SET a.shiftname =
                   (SELECT CASE
                              WHEN     TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (a.attendancedate), 'DAY') IN
                                          ('SATURDAY')
                                   AND week IN (2, 4)
                              THEN
                                 'WEEKLYOFF'
                              WHEN TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (a.attendancedate), 'WW') IN
                                      ('SUNDAY')
                              THEN
                                 'WEEKLYOFF'
                              ELSE
                                 'GENERAL1'
                           END
                      FROM (SELECT attendancedate,
                                   shiftname,
                                   ROW_NUMBER ()
                                      OVER (
                                         PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (
                                                         TO_DATE (attendancedate, 'DAY'))
                                         ORDER BY attendancedate) AS week
                              FROM t_attendance_attendance  a1
                                   LEFT JOIN t_attendance_user_master u
                                      ON u.loginid = a1.loginid
                                   LEFT JOIN t_attendance_employee_master e
                                      ON e.empid = u.empid
                             WHERE     a1.loginid = v_loginid
                                   AND e.company = ''
                                   AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM attendancedate) =
                                       EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
                                   AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM attendancedate) =
                                       EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE ())
                                   AND NVL (shiftname, '') = '') a);
      END IF;
   END proc_dashboard;
END pkg_attendance_dashboard;
```